# Como redirigir en woocomerce cuando un usuario no se registra adecuadamente

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

feliz año nuevo. Estoy haciendo un login mediante código en woocomerce he hecho una ventana popup pero me gustaria redirigir directamente a la pagina /registro si el usuario por ejemplo ingresa la verificación de la contraseña erroneamente. He pensado en el siguiente código pero tengo serias dudas de que sea la forma correcta.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors', 'registration_errors_validation', 10,3);
function registration_errors_validation($reg_errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {
global $woocommerce;
extract( $_POST );
if ( strcmp( $password, $password2 ) !== 0 ) {
    return new WP_Error( 'registration-error', __( 'Passwords do not match.', 'wc-vendors' ) );
}
return $reg_errors;
```

}

Mi idea es de poner en el condicional el código de redirección pero eso implicaria que no guardara el error. ¿que podria hacer?

Un saludo y gracias